# ROS - LaserScan moves instead of robot

Tags: ros, slam, rviz

I recently run into following problem.
While trying create a map from simulation data using *slam_toolbox*, my laserScan data are shifting based on robot movement instead of him. Robot stay in 0,0 position despite odometry changing.

Im sending data from simulator over UDP socket to ROS nodes that receive them and publish them to specific topics, these include /odom (receiver_node) and /scan (receiver_node2).

My launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="open_rviz" default="true" />

    <node pkg="slam_toolbox" type="sync_slam_toolbox_node" name="slam_toolbox" output="screen">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find analyzer_lab)/config/mapper_params_online_sync.yaml" />
    </node>

    <node pkg="analyzer_lab" type="receiver_node" name="receiver_node" output="screen"/>

    <node pkg="analyzer_lab" type="receiver_node2" name="receiver_node2" output="screen"/>

    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle.urdf.xacro laser_visual:=true" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />

    <node pkg="dynamic_transform_publisher" type="dynamic_transform_publisher" name="dynamic_tf_pub" >
        <rosparam>
            frame_id: odom
            child_frame_id: base_footprint
            x: 0.0
            y: 0.0
            z: 0.0
            roll: 0.0
            pitch: 0.0
            yaw: 0.0
            use_rpy : True
        </rosparam>
    </node>

    <node pkg="dynamic_transform_publisher" type="dynamic_transform_publisher" name="dynamic_tf_pub1" >
        <rosparam>
            frame_id: base_link
            child_frame_id: wheel_left_link
            x: 0.0
            y: 0.115
            z: 0.0
            roll: 0.0
            pitch: 0.0
            yaw: 0.0
            use_rpy : True
        </rosparam>
    </node>

    <node pkg="dynamic_transform_publisher" type="dynamic_transform_publisher" name="dynamic_tf_pub2" >
        <rosparam>
            frame_id: base_link
            child_frame_id: wheel_right_link
            x: 0.0
            y: -0.115
            z: 0.0
            roll: 0.0
            pitch: 0.0
            yaw: 0.0
            use_rpy : True
        </rosparam>
    </node>


    <!-- rviz -->
    <group if="$(arg open_rviz)">
      <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
        args="-d $(find analyzer_lab)/rviz/gmapping.rviz" />
    </group>
</launch>
```

Frames and transformations:
[image]

Nodes and topics:
[image]

Problem looks as follows:
[image]

After turning robot slightly left->
[image]

Please help!

I tried reversing transformations, adding specific dynamic_transformers instead of robot_state_publisher and simulation joint_states data, as seen in frames picture.

Comment: Have you changed your fixed frame?

Comment: Tried everyone available.